# iOS Swift Parse - key string contained in array not working

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, parse-platform

I have this piece of code that I use to query some events to my Parse database, Swift 1.2:

```
let keywordsArray = searchTxt.text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ") as [String]
// keywordsArray is an array made by separate words of a searchBar

// Make Parse query
eventsArray.removeAllObjects()
var query = PFQuery(className: "Events")
query.whereKey("keywords", containedIn: keywordsArray as [AnyObject])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error)-> Void in
```

I'm sure that the **keywords** field in my Parse database contains each word of the **keywordsArray**, but the result is always negative, that query cannot find anything.
I've double checked the words into the array with a **println()**, they are contained into **keywords** field in my Parse database, all lowercase strings, as my search is since the text into the searchBar is fully lowercase.

So may this be a Parse bug? I'm using the latest Parse SDK.
Am I missing something in that query?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your replies, I'll explain it better. 
**objects** in the completion handler fill an NSMutableArray called eventsArray, which is correctly initialized by **.removeAllObjects** before the query gets called. 
The console log gives no error and also no elements to the array, so no objects, here's an example:

-the keywords field in the Parse database, Events class, contains a sentence where "baseball" and "events" words are present (all lowercase words).

-keywordsArray is created by 2 words in the searchTxt, actually **baseball** and **event** so the console log actually gives me:

[baseball, event]

which are the items of **keywordsArray**.

So I don't understand why **eventsArray** is empty after the **for** loop shown in the code below:

```
   let keywordsArray = searchTxt.text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ") as [String]
  println("\(keywordsArray)") // <- prints = [baseball, event]

    // Make a new Parse query
    eventsArray.removeAllObjects()
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    query.whereKey("keywords", containedIn: keywordsArray as [AnyObject])
   // query.whereKey(EVENTS_KEYWORDS, containsString: searchTxt.text!.lowercaseString) // <- this is try I made but it doesn't work either so I've commented it out

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error)-> Void in
       if error == nil {
         if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
              for object in objects {
                 self.eventsArray.addObject(object)
       } }

println("\(self.eventsArray)") // <- This array comes up empty and no error by Parse on the Console log...
```

Comment: In the completion handler, what is the value of `objects` and `error`?

Comment: but the code is not finish you should check if there is an error then add to those objects to a new array

Comment: i am pretty sure it is not a parse bug. please provide an example searchText and an example keywords text that should match that search string.

Comment: I've edited my question, hope you can help me somehow :)